# Progress of the zlib compression

Tags: progress-bar, zlib

I am using zlib for zipping function in Linux.I would like to have the progress.On internet I found *gzoffset()*  but I do not have any idea about it. The zpipe.c - open source program .I need a progrees bar for this. It uses only inflate deflate options but not the *gz* . Could someone provide syntax for this or is there anyother command for showing the progress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html) to learn how to request gzip encoding and decoding. For a progress bar, determine the size of the input and show progress against the input.

Comment: So is _gzoffset_ the only option to show progress?

Comment: Just track the amount of input that has been consumed compared to the total input. Done.